# Setup java for MAC

Tags: java, macos

Im trying to download java for my MAC, but I dont know which platform should I choose just before downloading it, there is no MAC OS listed, so what should I choose instead? I used this URL for download

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u21-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java comes installed on your Mac already. Open `Terminal.app` from the Applications directory (or type `terminal` into Spotlight).

At the command line, type `java -version` to see exactly what you are running.

Answer (score 5):

As Noel posted, Java comes with the Mac, but if you want to update it, you can get [Apple's pre-packaged version of Java here](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl972). Note that you'll need Mac OS X 10.6.3 for that particular link, so you'll need to dig through Apple's support site to find the version relevant to your system if you're not already up to that Mac OS version.

The updates generally also show up in Software Update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java FAQ from Apple Site](http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/):

> How can I get Java for Mac OS X?
>
> Every version of Mac OS X comes with
>   Java out of the box. No download,
>   installation, or setup is necessary to
>   run applications, view Applets, or
>   even build your own Java code from the
>   command line. New Java releases are
>   made easily available through Software
>   Update, and developer packages can be
>   found at the Java Downloads page.